# Does the "Bad Behavior" anti-spam tool exist for phpBB?

Tags: phpbb

I've come across the highly praised anti-spam tool *["Bad Behavior"](http://bad-behavior.ioerror.us/).* There is a dead-simple WordPress plugin, but I also **want to use *Bad Behavior* with a forum powered by phpBB.**

[The Bad Behavior Installation Instructions](http://bad-behavior.ioerror.us/documentation/installation/) does list phpBB but is it deprecated.
I also had no luck [searching for existing phpBB MOD files](http://www.phpbb.com/mods/finding/).

What would be the best way to get *Bad Behavior* working with phpBB?

Answer (score 1):

The [bad behavior site](http://projects.phsoftware.de/projects/phbadbehave) does not say that it is "deprecated", rather it says that it is "legacy".   It appears to say that because version 2 of the product is ported to PHPBB but not version 3.

But then when [I click to see details](https://github.com/Androc/phBadBehave) it shows that version 3 has been ported as well.  After following a couple links, I find that it is [available from the current maintainer "Androc" on GitHub](https://github.com/Androc/phBadBehave).

Answer (score 0):

These plugins are released on editable licenses so you can update them yourself or pay someone to do it for you.

If you want to learn yourself then your need to learn how to using the phpBB documentation available. It's not a simple matter of adjusting a few lines hence why you have this answer.